# Question regarding range of addition of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I am required to find the range of the following trignometric function
$$2 \sin^2(x) + 2 \sin(x)$$

My approach to solving the above question has been as follows

The range of $2 \sin^2(x)$ must be $[0,2]$ and the range for $2 \sin(x)$ is from [-2, 2] so therefore the range of the function $2 \sin^2(x) + 2 \sin(x) = [-2, 4]$ however the graph for the above function i.e. $2 \sin^2(x) + 2 \sin(x)$ is as follows

[image]

This is in desmos why is this function from -0.5 to 4 is what i do not understand could someone please explain this to me.

Am i missing something out?

Any help would be appreictaed!

Comment: The reason you can't just add the minimum of one function to the minimum of the other function and add the maximum of one function to the maximum of the other is that two arbitrary functions don't necessarily reach their minima and maxima at the exact same values of $x$. In this case the functions **do** reach their maxima at the same $x$, but they reach their minima at different values of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the ranges of each part of an expression *only* shows where the overall expression range must lie within, since the minima and maxima of each part may not coincide. To determine your actual range, we could use [derivatives](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_(mathematics)). However, since your expression is a quadratic in $\sin(x)$, using the simpler [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) instead gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2\sin^2(x) + 2\sin(x) & = 2(\sin^2(x) + \sin(x)) \\
& = 2\left(\sin^2(x) + \sin(x) + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}\right) \\
& = 2\left(\sin(x) + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

The minimum value of $\left\lvert \sin(x) + \frac{1}{2}\right\rvert$ is $0$ when $\sin(x) = -\frac{1}{2}$ (e.g., when $x = -30^{\circ}$). This gives a minimum expression value of $2(0) - \frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}$. The maximum value of $\left\lvert \sin(x) + \frac{1}{2}\right\rvert$ is $\frac{3}{2}$ when $\sin(x) = 1$ (e.g., when $x = 90^{\circ}$), giving a maximum expression value of $2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{2} = 2\left(\frac{9}{4}\right) - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{9}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = 4$. This range matches what you got in your Desmos graph.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add together the ranges of the two functions, what is true is that if you take the the derivative of $f$ and set it to $0$ you obtain:
$$f'(x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x) + \cos(x)=0$$
At this point it's important to realize that if $f(x)$ is $0$ for some value of $x$, that value cannot be of the form $k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ so the cosine function we find in the derivative is never $0$.
$$\Rightarrow 2\sin(x)=-1 \Rightarrow x=\frac{-\pi}{6}$$
plugging the value in $f$ you get $f(\frac{-\pi}{6})-\frac{-1}{2}$ 
the maximum is found evaluating in $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and is equal to 4.
Clearly this function is $2\pi-$periodic so all the values for $x$ are $(mod\,2\pi)$